# Excel selecting last value in range for a updated list macro

Tags: vba, excel

I'd appreciate help with the following....

I'm using a validation list function, but I will need people to add to the list easily. So I recorded a macro and will link it from a button, so they just need to add a new value and click the button. The problem is I need it to find the last populated cell in that column. I've looked online and on here, but because I'm completely new to VBA I can't figure out how to edit it.

Here is the code, I need it to select D4 to the last populated value in column D.

```
Range("F5").Select
ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeSameValidation).Select
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=Filters!$D$4:$D$21"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
Range("G15").Select
```

Thanks!!

Comment: do you mean you have a list that is used to validate other cells, but this list needs to be dynamic etc ?   and then you want D4 to show the last value added to the list ?

Comment: If only need to have a dynamic validation list - you can just use a formula for that.

Comment: The validation list is used in an used for recording information e.g. name, address, postcode, category.  The category needs to be consistent and fixed, so the best way is to force the user to pick from a validation list.

What I'm trying to do is make the admin of it easy, so when the need comes to add a new category to the source of the list, they only need to add the new item and run the macro to update the validation.

My problem here is my macro is looking at an exact range"Filters!$D$4:$D$21, when I need it to do a range of $D$4 to the last populated cell in that column.

Thanks

Comment: did you search for "Excel dynamic validation list" before posting?  It shouldn't require any VBA; just a Named Range using the `offset` function or a `Table Range`.  The only reason you would need VBA, is if your trying to hide the list from the users and automatically adding new entries.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this it what you want but here is code for finding the last (bottom) filled in cell in a column. Call it as lastRow = findLastRow(yoursheetname, yourcolumnname (like "F:F" or a named column) ):

```
Option Explicit

Function findLastRow(Sheetname As String, ColumnName As String)
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim r As Range
    Dim WS As Worksheet

    Set WS = Worksheets(Sheetname)
    lastRow = WS.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    '*
    '* Search backwards till we find a cell that is not empty
    '*
    Set r = WS.Range(ColumnName).Rows(lastRow)
    While r.Value = ""
        Set r = r.Offset(-1, 0)
    Wend
    lastRow = r.Row
    Set WS = Nothing
    findLastRow = lastRow
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 easy ways to deal with this.

1. Formatted Tables
2. Named Range using an `Offset()`

Just put you list(s) on another `admin/config/list` sheet to get it out of the way.

Here are a few good sites explaining how to do it, if you search `Excel dynamic validation list`

http://excelsemipro.com/2011/05/a-dynamic-dependent-drop-down-list-in-excel/

http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4021-excel-data-validation-dynamic-range.html

https://chandoo.org/wp/2010/09/13/dynamic-data-validation-excel/

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-create-a-dynamic-validation-control-in-excel/